# Can we change the device time using an application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, timezone, ios4

Want to know whether its possible to change the time of the iPhone through an application.. Is that level of dev access granted in iOS4?

My gut feeling is no, but I'm looking for a definitive Yes/No answer if possible.

Note: NSTimeZone class states 'Cocoa does not provide any API to change the time zone of the computer, or of other applications.'

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

No this functionality is not possible via the official iphone SDK.

Comment: Is there any unofficial way?

Comment: Probably - I don't know it though.