# Change iphone time

Tags: iphone

I want to set the time of system in the iphone application,but i don't know how to do.
Would you know? Please tell me,thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we change the device time using an application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121287/can-we-change-the-device-time-using-an-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, as there is no public API provided by Apple to do that. Even then, it's bad practice to try and change a user system setting like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, check out this forum link:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/51285-can-we-change-device-time-using-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Use an NSDate and then modify it accordingly.

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    int hour = [[now dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] hourOfDay];
    int min = [[now dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] minuteOfHour];
    int sec = [[now dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] secondOfMinute];
    NSLog(@"%d  /  %d  /  %d", hour+offset1, min+offset2, sec+offset2);
```

But you truly can't change the system clock. But, maybe this will help with what you want to do.