# Any api to change iphone's system time?

Tags: iphone, date, time, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we change the device time using an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121287/can-we-change-the-device-time-using-an-application)

is that possible to update system time programatically in ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked, but if you want your app in the AppStore I recommend to not do that. Apple will surely reject it, for example on the ground that this is duplicating system functionality. You are not supposed (or allowed) to modify the system, and even changing the time will likely count.